# Is there a way to directly run pytorch on an iPhone without using Swift or CoreML?

Tags: ios, iphone, pytorch

As title.

I have tried to use apps in iOS like `iSH` and `a-Shell` to build a linux-like environment to run pytorch (training a small network directly without using Swift and such). However, they cannot be installed. Is there a way for iPhone to use an app (like `termux` in Android) to train (instead of just inference) a deep network in pytorch directly?